# Powershell - What kind of value does Get-MailboxFolderStatistics return?

Tags: powershell

I have a little question for you, because I did not find anything so far.

If I use the Cmd-let Get-MailboxFolderStatistics and format it as list or table, it creates a very nice output, but the problem is, I want to use some of the values returned.
So, what kind of string is returned? It's not an array, it's not an ordinary string and I could'nt cast it to a string, for further manipulation.

If I print the returned value on the shell, everything is right, what means it at least gets the right information.

Am I on a completely wrong path for working on the output?

Any help is appreciated!!
Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-MailboxStatistics` returns objects of the type `MailboxStatistics`

Know more about the class here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.data.mapi.mailboxstatistics.aspx

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell cmdlets return objects, not strings, so you can `select` the properties you're interested in. Example:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics <id> | select Name,FolderSize
```

Piping the output into `Get-Member` will provide you with a list of the object's properties and methods:

```
Get-MailboxFolderStatistics <id> | Get-Member
```